# How to run a predicate that contains lists as argument using GNU Prolog for Java?

Tags: java, prolog, ffi

I tried to use the library gnu prolog for java to execute a prolog file. I managed to make it work for a basic predicate, but when I try to parse lists the output of prolog engine, it does not work correctly.

My java code is as follows:

```
    gnu.prolog.vm.Environment environment = new Environment();
environment.ensureLoaded(AtomTerm.get(PrologTest.class.getResource("main.pro").getFile()));

    gnu.prolog.vm.Interpreter interp = environment.createInterpreter();
    environment.runInitialization(interp);

    Term[] listElements = { new IntegerTerm(1), new IntegerTerm(2)};
    Term termElements = new CompoundTerm(TermConstants.listTag, listElements);
    Term[] listElements2 =  { new IntegerTerm(1), new IntegerTerm(2)};
    Term termElements2 = new CompoundTerm(TermConstants.listTag, listElements2);
    Term[]argumentsQuestion = {termElements,termElements2};

    CompoundTerm goalTerm = new CompoundTerm(AtomTerm.get("same"), argumentsQuestion);

    int rc;
    Interpreter.Goal goal = interp.prepareGoal(goalTerm);
     rc = interp.execute(goal); 
     System.out.println("rc value"+rc); 
        if (rc == PrologCode.SUCCESS || rc == PrologCode.SUCCESS_LAST)
        { System.out.println("OK"); }else{
      System.out.println("error"); }
```

My file main.pro contains the following predicate:

```
same([H1|R1], [H2|R2]):- H1 is H2 , same (R1,R2).
same([], []) :- true.
```

The problem is the value of rc is always -1. I tried to modify the file main.pro as follows:

```
same([H1|R1], [H2|R2]):- H1 is H2.
same([], []) :- true.
```

The program works correctly in this case, so the program parses correctly the list and reads correctly the first value of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard `is/2` predicate performs *arithmetic evaluation* by evaluating the second argument as an arithmetic expression and unifying the result with the first argument.

Try instead:

```
same([H| R1], [H| R2]):- same(R1,R2).
same([], []).
```

But note this accomplishes the same as the following much simpler definition:

```
same(List, List).
```

or:

```
List1 = List2
```

Maybe you want/need to use *term equality* instead of *term unification* as in the solutions above? If that's the case, try:

```
same([H1| R1], [H1| R2]):- H1 == H2, same(R1,R2).
same([], []).
```

Comment: Thank you so much , the  definition same(List,List) is the correct one